# Why this narrowing conversion (Maximum long value to byte) has the value of -1?

Tags: java

I used this site for conversion:
https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-decimal-converter

9223372036854775807 is represented as 0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

And a byte takes up 1 byte, which is 8 bit, so the last 8 bit is: 11111111
**Converting this back to a number using the website linked above I get 255, not -1.**

Please see my code.

Thank you very much for helping me out.

```
   long l = 9223372036854775807L;
   System.out.println("Value of B: " + l);

   byte b = (byte) (l);
   System.out.println("Value of B: " + b);
```

This has the following result:

```
Value of B: 9223372036854775807
Value of B: -1
```

Comment: Did you look at the range of values that a `byte` can hold in Java? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1

Comment: I do not know about that website, but in Java a byte with binary `11111111` is `-1` (8 bit signed two complement integer) - not only in Java: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly normal, because in Java bytes go from -128 to 127, not from 0 to 255.  -1 in a Java signed byte corresponds to 255 in an unsigned byte.

Comment: Isn't the most significant bit a sign bit? So -1 in a signed byte would be 10000001? Or am I mixing it up with C++...

Comment: @TylerV You are mixing it up. In [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), −1 is binary 11111111.

Comment: Thank you so it basically depends only if a byte is signed or unsigned (so if it is interpreted for negative / positive range as well or the whole range is on the non negative area) So the website I used calculated bytes for the latter case, while java's byte falls under the first case. Thats why a small recalculation is needed using a table from the linked source.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte byteVal = (byte)238; // -18
int intVal = byteVal; // sign extended to maintain 2's complement value
System.out.println(byteVal); 
System.out.println(intVal);
```

prints

```
-18
-18
```

- To print a `byte` as an unsigned value, AND it with `0xFF (255)`.
- the byte is converted to an `int` as above.
- the `ANDing` of the value preserves the lower `8 bits`.

```
System.out.println(byteVal&0xFF);
```

prints

```
238
```